# C# Generic method with IGrouping having any type on key

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to build a generic method that shoudl receive an IGrouping of a specific type, but the key should have any value. My current solution is as follows:

```
public static List<T> ApplyPagedCriteriaGrouping<T, U>(this IQueryable<T> query, Criteria criteria) where T : IGrouping<U, DomainObject>
```

Although the above works, when calling the method I have to do as following:

```
query.ApplyPagedCriteriaGrouping<IGrouping<long, SomeClass>, long>(criteria);
```

As you can see, I have to type long twice, as it needs to be the same. Can I simplify this in any other way?

Comment: No. Other questions? :-) But be happy... many persons have this problem :-)

Comment: That's a shame :'( Well, it could be worse.

Comment: It could rain :-) If you have to explicitly write the generic type you have to write it fully. It is on-off. The compiler can auto-discover it or you have to write it fully. No gray :-)

Comment: If you strongly typed the `criteria` variable, you wouldn't need to specify the generic terms.

Comment: You can´t determine only a few generic arguments. Either determine all or none.